# CD Recorder that can burn directly to CD from Microphone and burn to another disc?

Tags: audio-recording

I am looking for something that will enable me to record/burn directly to a cd and if possible making another copy of the burned disc, so I don't have to burn it to a computer hard-drive first and then burn it to a blank disc.  Is there anything like that?  If burning to another disc is not an option, then what are some good cd recorders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CDR882?utm_source=CSE&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=none&utm_term=CDR882-Dual_Pro_CD_Burner_Player&SID=0&zmam=89202644&zmas=1&zmac=1&zmap=CDR882) will be about what you are looking for.  It can record 2 cd's at once and has balanced inputs so you can plug the microphone directly in, although you may need a pre-amp for the mic.

To get more options just do a Google search on "[dual cd recorder](http://www.google.com/search?q=dual%20cd%20recorder&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=dual%20cd%20recorder&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=G72&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=dZ7STefKHciBtgf-w-CjCg&ved=0CHIQrQQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7b2a1dda4f65c836&biw=1600&bih=1051)" and you should be able to find some additional options.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if they have options to burn to more than just 2 at a time?

Comment: How many cd's are you looking to burn at once?

Comment: Well, its not really for me, I was just curious if you can do dual, what is the maximum that some product has out there.  This is basically mainly for voice recording, but the option to burn to multiple discs like dual would be nice.

Comment: I really don't know much about multi-disc recording.  I use a computer to record audio and burn to cd.  I recommend you do some searches for that type of equipment.  Google is a great place to start.

Comment: Yeah, that is how I normally would do multi-disc recording as well.  Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Roland CD-2e. Look it up online it is awesome. I use it for all my vocal lessons AND record my shows LIVE right to a CD or SD card if I want to edit it!